# Call a datafusion pipeline from GCP Workflows

Tags: google-cloud-platform, workflow, google-cloud-data-fusion

Is there any working example of initiating a Datafusion pipeline from Cloud workflows, and how authentication is handled?
I am used to calling CDF pipelines with Cloud functions, but need to orchestrate them. Hence, the requirement.

Comment: It's an API call. Do you have issues with the documentation? If so, where

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/cdap-reference#start_a_batch_pipeline), there is a way to trigger Cloud Data Fusion pipelines using REST API. You can use the following command to trigger a pipeline from Cloud workflows:

```
POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $ {AUTH_TOKEN}" "$ {CDAP_ENDPOINT}/v3/namespaces/<namespace-id>/apps/<pipeline-name>/workflows/DataPipelineWorkflow/start"
```

Comment: My issue was more with generating the AUTH_TOKEN using cloud workflow.